# Create android.graphics.Path object from String

Tags: java, android, vector, vector-graphics

I have a string with the following value:

```
String pathData = "M532.09,525.72a40.32,40.32 0,0 0,5 31.09,29.41 29.41,0 0,0 4.33,5.41 11.18,11.18 0,0 0,4.43 2.92l0.08,0c1.45,
        0.36 3.72,0.07 6.37,-0.84L554,546.6q0,-0.32 0.09,-0.63a6.36,6.36 0,0 1,0.36 -1.17c0.08,-0.19 0.17,-0.37 0.26,-0.55a6.19,6.19 0,
        0 1,10.58 -0.52,6.09 6.09,0 0,1 1,4l-0.76,8a40,40 0,0 0,11 -19.15c4.11,-16.69 -3.63,-29 -15.7,-32a21.65,21.65 0,0 0,-21.8 7.1,
        32.51 32.51,0 0,0 -6.94,13.88Z"
```

How can I convert this string into a  android.graphics.Path object?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
androidx.core.graphics.PathParser.createPathFromPathData(pathData)
```